# Mac - import requests error - requests module exists

Tags: python, python-requests, python-import, importerror

import requests in python is not working.
When i do so, it shows me the ImportError

**ImportError**: No module named moves

Google Search doesn't give any solution. Someone please help me out.

[image]

Comment: did you install six?

Comment: Try removing requests (using whatever tool you used to install it), and then install it again (e.g. `pip install requests`).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Thomas for your answer.
Well, uninstalling the requests module didn't actually deleted it from the mac. So, i needed to manually delete the module from my system and then installed it using pip install requests.